# Sketchapp using for mockup designing

Tags: macos, user-interface, frontend, web-frontend, mockups

I know this is not related to PHP but related to many Front-end designers and developers.

In now days experienced mockup or UI/UX element designer use an app called [sketchapp](https://www.sketchapp.com/) specially who use [mac os](http://www.apple.com/osx/). but when it comes to front-end developers who don't have [mac os](http://www.apple.com/osx/) to code front-end. Here is the problem start many of developers try to search a solution but I don't think any one had it because the app developers not create any thing for windows to support these files.

My Question: what is the solution for this problem? should we try to find a friend/colleague who have mac os with the app or should we ask the client for other file format (but sometime clients don't have other file formats) or should we reject the project.

what should we do?

Answer (score 0):

The immediate solution is to have your clients *export their Sketch files to pdf*. That is a built-in function in Sketch and only takes a second.
Longterm you may want to evaluate whether or not you maybe should get a cheap Mac to expand your portfolio.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but if you need to get design specs to work with you could use:

https://zeplin.io/
OR
https://www.invisionapp.com/

They offer tools for collaboration between designers and developers.

Hope this helps!